# String stops displaying after 1st accentued character

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, non-ascii-characters

**Problem with Laravel 4 beta 3 :

A string stops displaying after 1st accentued character.**

I have a DB table where I store DVD entries (title,director,...)

The DB is `utf_8`, collation for title is `utf8_unicode_ci`

the database.php config file indicates `utf8_unicode_ci`
.......
In the model (extends Eloquent) :

```
class Dvdentry extends Eloquent {
public $table = 'dvd_entry';
public $timestamps = false;
}
```

.........
In the controller :

```
  $entries=Dvdentry::where($field,'like',$ulike)->get();
```

........
In the view :

```
 @foreach($entries as $entry)
    <a href={{$entry->imdb_link}} page=_blank>{{$entry->title}}</a>
```

....
That should display a list of titles.
For the titles that has an accent in it (i.e Mépris (Le) ), only the M is

displayed.
I have tried with no success :

```
 {{{$entry->title}}}
 <?php echo $entry->title; ?>
 <?php echo utf_decode($entry->title); ?>
```

.........
Any clue. Thks for help.

Comment: It would be interesting to know where this is happening. If you dump `$entries` in your controller, is the data as you would expect?

Comment: @juco A dump just after the query (in the controler) shows that accented char are missing : <br/>string 'Reservoir Dogs' (length=14)<br/> string 'M' (length=1) instead of 'Mépris'<br/> string 'Valseuses (Les)' (length=15)<br/>code :<br/>    $entries=Dvdentry::where($field,'like',$ulike)->get();<br/> foreach($entries as $entry) { <br/>var_dump($entry->title);<br/> };

Comment: OK solved. I have a corrupted DB after copy (Export/Import) into a Development DB (MySQL 5.5.2.4, PHPmyAdmin 3.5.1) from a production DB (MySQL 5.0, PHPmyAdmin 2.6.4). I have yet to find why the copy does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the e() helper?

> e() - Run htmlentites over the given string, with UTF-8 support.

```
$entities = e('<html>foo</html>');
```

---

Check the Laravel Documentation at this point: http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#strings

I'm also speculating that the accents cause Blade to fail. Try to encode the titles before saving in the DB. So the accents are encoded in HTML Entities…

```
Mépris => M&eacute;pris
```